# Spring boot модульный проект. Gradle не ищет properties в модулях

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

Изучаю потихоньку Gradle и Spring Boot. Так же решил попробовать разделить проект на модули.
Проблема в том, что как только я в модуле Service(импортирует модуль Repository) добавляю файл application.properties (или yml) то файл в Repository игнорируется(выпадает ошибка создания бина потому что `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required key 'db.driver' not found`  а `db.driver` в application.properties Repository модуля определен), а если файла нет то он идет в модуль и файл видит(по крайней мере все работает), есть подозрение что найдя ближайший application.properties файл оно дальше не ищет. Как решить эту проблему, ведь по логике в каждом модуле свой собственный конфиг и к примеру если будет еще 3й модуль web то там конфиг базы точно не к чему

Структура проекта: 
[image: Структура проекта]

build.gradle модуля Repository

```
group 'S'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M4'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
        maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

ext {
    hibernateEntitymanagerVersion = '5.2.10.Final'
    mysqlConnectorJavaVersion = '5.1.34'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernateEntitymanagerVersion}")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlConnectorJavaVersion}")

    runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:${springBootVersion}")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
}
```

build.gradle модуля Service

```
group 'S'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M4'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
        maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    maven { setUrl("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':SprGrdMod-Repository')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")

    runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:${springBootVersion}")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше подозрение верно - найдя в classpath первый попавшийся `application.properties` (или `application.yml`) Spring прекращает поиск дефолтных property source. В ресурсы библиотек он за дефолтными property source не полезет, если дефолтный property source есть в основном приложении.

Как это обойти?

Можно явно указать источник свойств для ваших классов в аннотации `@PropertySource`:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:library.properties")
public class LibraryConfiguration {
}
```

Минусом такого подхода является невозможность использования в `@PropertySource` YAML - только `.properties`, только хардкор. Также важно отметить, что использовать имя `application.properties` при наличии такого файла в основном приложении не получится - Spring подхватит именно его, а не файл из библиотеки.

Если же хочется именно YAML, то можно создать initializer, который прочитает YAML-конфиг и запишет всойства из него в контекст приложения (код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349492/4863012)):

```
public class YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        try {
            // Здесь я захардкодил имя конфига, но вы всегда можете
            // написать более сложную логику его поиска
            Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:library.yml");
            YamlPropertySourceLoader sourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
            PropertySource<?> yamlProperties =
                    sourceLoader.load("yamlProperties", resource, null);
            applicationContext
                    .getEnvironment()
                    .getPropertySources()
                    .addFirst(yamlProperties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы Spring Boot использовал этот initializer, нужно указать его в `META-INF/spring.factories`:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=com.example.YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer
```

Теперь Spring увидит проперти, записанные в вашем файле. Как и в предыдущем случае, назвать файл `application.yml` не выйдет - `applicationContext.getResource("classpath:library.yml")` загрузит файл из основного приложения.

Впрочем, в обоих случаях конфиги из библиотеки будут видны в основном приложении. Spring не подразумевает разделение конфигов по JAR-файлам, они видны всем бинам в контексте. Поэтому стремление разбить конфиги по модулям, в общем-то, бесполезно. А с некоторой точки зрения даже вредно. Держа все конфиги в одном файле, вы будете иметь единую точку входа для изменения конфигурации приложения. Вам не придётся думать, в каком файле какого модуля то или иное проперти, и не придётся мучиться, переопределяя их для другого окружения.